# Setting height and width of Canvas app using force:canvasApp

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas

We're exploring using force:canvasApp in a community.  We are finding that the height and width declarations specified by [force:canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_canvasApp.htm) don't seem to be having any effect on the displayed component.

Is this a known issue (I couldn't find anything in the bug log) or are we missing some important element of embedding a canvas app inside a lightning component in a community?

Comment: Over 2 years later, no fix, no response?!?! :-(